# Angular-ui-router call state template Controllers only one time

Tags: controller, angular-ui-router

Im new in angular-ui-router.

I need to call controller methods in templates only one time.
Now controllers in template calls each time when state become active. 
In each template I have a lot of data initialization and state switching takes long time.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            templateUrl: "app"
        })
        .state('app.accounts', {
            url: "/app.accounts",
            templateUrl: "app.accounts"
        })
        .state('settings', {
            url: "/settings",
            templateUrl: "settings"
        })
        .state('app.transactions', {
            url: "/app.transactions",
            templateUrl: "app.transactions"
        }).state('app.equity', {
            url: "/app.equity",
            templateUrl: "app.equity"
        }).state('app.loans', {
            url: "/app.loans",
            templateUrl: "app.loans"
        });
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent this behavior. The $scope get's destroyed when you leave the scope.
You may want to implement an caching functionality, or redesign your controller(s).

Comment: Jens, as far as I understand. In this case better way to use angular-ui-route as a manager of display menu templates? For example load all templates using <div ng-include="templateName" ng-cloack ng-show="show Flag"> And change using angular-ui-route showFlag of current state.

Comment: Hi ZNick, sorry for the Delay... First of all, '''ng-cloak''' is used during the initial App-loading to prevent showing unfinished Views. If you want to Show fixes Views to the user, you shouldn't use '''ng-include'''. You should create a directive for that instead. <br>I am working currently on on an Angular Seed App that makes use of the ui-router. You Kay want to take a Look at https://github.com/JensEger/Angular-OAuth-RouteResolver-Seed/tree/develop <br> you can see there how i use directives and how i use the ui-router for Routine and (later) for dynamic route resolving.